# Cocoon Gem: Edit view is only showing empty form fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, many-to-many, cocoon-gem

I am using cocoon in my Rails app for assigning employees (users) to projects (many to many connection). The creation of associations is working correctly, but each time I add another employee cocoon adds an empty form field in the edit view. None of the other cocoon form fields in the edit view are populated either. Could this be due to the usage of dropdowns (select)?

When I inspect the form in my browser I can see that each field seems to be assigned to one of the associations, but the selection is still empty.
[image]

What I would like to achieve is, that every association is displayed in a cocoon form field, so that they can be edited. Thanks for any help in advance!

My code is below (Sorry for any mess, it is my first time trying out a many to many connection of two models).

**Project Edit View**

```
 <%= form_for(@project, :url => project_path, method: :patch) do |f| %>

    <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :title %>
        <%= f.text_field :title, class: "form-control" %>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :customer %>
        <%= f.text_field :customer, class: "form-control" %>
    </div>

    <%= f.fields_for :user_projects do |collab| %>
        <% collab.hidden_field :project_id, value: @project.id %>
        <%= render 'user_project_fields', f: collab %>
    <% end %>
    <div class="add-collaborator">
        <%= link_to_add_association "add", f, :user_projects, class: "btn btn-mmc" %>
    </div>

    <div class="actions">
        <%= f.submit "Save Changes", class: "btn btn-mmc btn-mmc-medium" %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

**cocoon field partial**

```
<div class="nested-fields">
    <%= f.label "Select User" %>
    <div class="form-group custom-form-group">
        <%= f.select(:user_id, options_for_select(User.all.map { |u| [u.email, u.id] }), {include_blank: true}, {class: 'form-control'})%>
        <div class="btn-user-project">
            <%= link_to_remove_association "x", f, class: "btn btn-mmc-attention btn-mmc" %>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Project Model**

```
class Project < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :user_projects
    has_many :users, :through => :user_projects

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_projects, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
end
```

**User Model**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
    # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
    devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

    has_many :user_projects
    has_many :projects, :through => :user_projects
end
```

**Project Controller**

```
def edit
    @project = Project.find(params[:id])
    @project.user_projects.build
end

def update
    @project = Project.find(params[:id])
    @project.update(project_params)
    @new_collaborator = UserProject.new(user_id: params[:user_id], project_id: params[:project_id])
    @new_collaborator.save
    if @project.update(project_params) && @new_collaborator.save
        redirect_to projects_path
    else
        render :edit
    end
end

private

def project_params
    params.require(:project).permit(:title, :customer, :delted, user_projects_attributes: [:user_id, :project_id]).reject { |_, v| v.blank? }
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing the mapping to the actual value is not done correctly, e.g. the value of the `user_id` is not marked as selected, in the `options_for_select` you have to add the selected value as parameter (see [documentation](https://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.3/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_for_select)).

However, there is a much easier version:

```
<%= f.collection_select(:user_id, User.all, :id, :email) %>
```

BTW using a gem like `simple_form` also makes building forms a lot more intuitive and straightforward.

Comment: Thank you very much! This solved my problem instantly! 

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're create object twice.

First time:

```
@project.update(project_params) # from accepts_nested_attributes_for
```

Second time:

```
@new_collaborator = UserProject.new(user_id: params[:user_id], project_id: params[:project_id])
@new_collaborator.save
```

P.s.

Can you show `project_params` method? I think I know why first object empty

Comment: Thank you! You were right, it did indeed save everything twice and your suggestion fixed this. However all fields in my edit view are still empty. I edited my original post and added the project_params function (at the end of the controller) and a screenshot which hopefully clarifies what my problem is.

Comment: @Frederike Understood, however the problem lies elsewhere. For building a many to many association you should use code like this: `user.projects << project`
In addition, I advise you to read this: https://github.com/pluralsight/guides/blob/master/published/ruby-ruby-on-rails/ruby-on-rails-nested-attributes/article.md

Comment: Thank you, this is a really good guide. Unfortunately, it does not solve my front-end problem. The many to many associations are working by now but they are not displayed correctly, which is I guess due to me using dropdowns and not pure text input fields. So I guess the problem is rather a jQuery problem.